# Minecraft 1.8.9 Disabling control in other applications

Tags: 20.04, java, minecraft

I have recently installed Minecraft java 1.8.9 (Optifine), and when the application is open I can't use my mouse or keyboard in any other app.

After installing a older version of java, I finally got the older version of the game to launch. I believe that the different version of java is the root of my problem.

Any Solution to my problem would be appreciated.

Comment: Would that not be a question for the Minecraft people?

Comment: My issue is not that the game is not working, it is that it is preventing me from multi-tasking or just using other applications altogether. This same issue does not occur on Mac OS or Windows, so i am asking it here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a simple solution.Shortly before I posted this response, I figured out that this issue will only occur when Minecraft is in full screen. Since I only wanted to tab out of the application, it was hardly any effort to press F11 to exit full screen, then press it again when I wanted to go back into Minecraft.

Another way to do this is to create a borderless windowed fullscreen window. To do this, You will need to install gnome tweaks, specifically extensions, and install these 3:

1.GTK Title Bar
2. Hide Top Bar
3. Hide Top Panel

Simily activate these 3 when you go into minecraft,and your issues will be solved.
Also make sure to activate Auto-hide the Dock, in settings (Appearance -> Dock).